# How to parse an XML file in Scala using VTD-XML library?

Tags: scala, xpath, vtd-xml

Does Anyone know How to parse large XML files using *Xpath* using **vtd-xml** library in **Scala**?

Comment: Do you still have the problems you reported here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126703/arrayindexoutofboundexception-in-scala-program-usind-vtd-xml?

Comment: I dont know what happened .? But it works Well Now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my local machine:

```
import com.ximpleware.{VTDGen, VTDNav, AutoPilot}

val vtdgen = new VTDGen()
val autopilot = new AutoPilot()
autopilot.selectXPath("/CATALOG/CD/COUNTRY/text()")
if (vtdgen.parseFile("catalog.xml", false)) {
  val vtdnav = vtdgen.getNav()
  autopilot.bind(vtdnav)
  var i = -1
  while({i = autopilot.evalXPath; i} != -1) {
    println(vtdnav.toString(i))
    println(vtdnav.toNormalizedString(vtdnav.getText()))
  }
}
autopilot.resetXPath()
```

Outputs on input of [catalog.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126703/arrayindexoutofboundexception-in-scala-program-usind-vtd-xml/5142362#5142362):

```
USA
USA
UK
UK
UK
UK
USA
USA
```

Answer (score 1):

**@ huynhjl** :Thank You.. It Works Well.

Use

```
println(vtdnav.toString(i-1))
println(vtdnav.toNormalizedString(vtdnav.getText()))
```

to get  the output as

```
COUNTRY
USA
COUNTRY
UK
COUNTRY
UK
COUNTRY
USA
```